# Insert data into nested tables SQLite in Air for Android

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have three SQLite tables `Schools` `Classes` and `Students`. One `School` consists of multiple `Classes` and each `Class` in turn consists of multiple `Students`.

On my application (Air for Android), I have some class structure like this

```
class School { id:uint; name:String; classArray:ArrayList}
class Class { id:uint; name:String; studentArray:ArrayLisy}
class Student { id:uint; name:String}
```

As the application is targeted at mobile platform, I would like to minimize the number of queries sent as much as possible. I'm new to SQL so at the moment I just loop through every elements, which is quite inefficient. Is there some kind of compound query or special keyword that can help achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AIR SQL Classes don't parse custom objects, you cant pass it an object and/or special keywords, it only operates on `String`s. I would recommend writing `.toSQLInsertString()`, `toSQLUpdateString()` functions on your data objects to reduce the amount of object inspections, but you will have to loop through collections.

I recommend reading up on [Adobe AIR: SQLConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5497-7fb4.html)

Comment: I doh't pass the object itself. I retrieve an instance of, let's say, myClass:Class = new Class() then I use INSERT INTO Classes (id, name) VALUES (?,?) and provide the values by parementers[] = ... is it an acceptable way of doing it?

Comment: thanks for the link, I'll do more read-up. Just need some kind of quick solution at the moment

Comment: Yes, your first comment would a quick way of implementing it. You could even create a function on your classes that would return the `SQLStatement` ready to execute. Just be careful, SQL can be punishing, if you don't design your Database properly now it can cause long delays in recovering data further down the line.

Comment: Thanks for the help! If there is no way but looping through all collections then I guess you have answered my main question. Checked